# Отсупы в HTML-таблице

Tags: html, css, popup, отступы

Саму проблему вы можете увидеть на картинке (думаю описывать не надо) 
https://pp.vk.me/c606424/v606424182/50f/R0RVW1TqmZE.jpg

Как убрать этот отступ справа? Вот код https://pp.vk.me/c606424/v606424182/521/OZRQPbvMtYg.jpg

Оффтоп:
У меня до сих пор не получается вставлять коды так что я по свойму.( модеры не ругайте)

Comment: дайте ссылку на сайт или разместите код на jsfiddle.net.

А то так ну совсем ничего не понятно.

Comment: Это не сайт.. Точнее он не га хосте а локально на компе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ой, сударь, у вас html 3.2 :)
раритет, однако!

Может тогда и решать методами, характерными для html 3.2? Например,

```
<table width=100%>
```

Comment: Html 3.2? Ого сам не знал) но жело в том что когда картинка не вставлена то таблица во всю ширину точнее диалоговое окно шириной как таблица, а вот когда картинка вот что происходит

Comment: это скорее шутка :) Хотя в ней и присутствует доля правды.

такие милые нюансы как тэг center или border=1 … :)